# Promisifying xml2js parse function (ES6 Promises)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to refactor some node code that is a whole mess of callbacks. I thought that would be nice give promises a try for this purpose. I'm trying to convert some xml string to json with the `xml2js` node module. The original code was:

```
"use strict";

var xml2jsParser = require('xml2js').parseString;

var string = "<container><tag3>option3</tag3></container>";

xml2jsParser(string, function(err, result)
{
    console.log(result);
});
```

and this displays:

```
{ container: { tag1: [ 'option1' ], tag2: [ 'option2' ], tag3: [ 'option3' ] } }
```

Following the first answer on this question [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises?lq=1) I tried to wrap the xml2jsParser function using promises in the following way:

```
"use strict";

var xml2jsParser = require('xml2js').parseString;

function promisesParser(string)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        xml2jsParser(string, resolve);
    });
}

var string = "<container><tag3>option3</tag3></container>";

promisesParser(string).then(function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

This displays `undefined` through the console instead of the json object as expected. I don't understand why this happens as I was able to successfully do the same with other functions. I know something similar can be achieved with Bluebird promisify functionality but I'd like to do this on plain Javascript without any third party libraries.

Comment: Use #3 "node style callback" not #2 "plain callback" from that answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are going to need to wrap it up like this:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
{
    xml2jsParser(string, function(err, result){
         if(err){
             reject(err);
         }
         else {
             resolve(result);
         }
    });
});
```

Then use it like this:

```
promisesParser(string).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
}).catch(function(err){
    //error here
});
```

Answer (score 18):

Another option is to use native `util` module's `promisify` method, [available from Node 8.0](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original):

```
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const util = require('util');

xml2js.parseStringPromise = util.promisify(xml2js.parseString);

// await xml2js.parseStringPromise(.. your xml ..);
```

Comment: Or `xml2js.Parser.prototype.parseStringPromise = util.promisify(xml2js.parseString);` if you'll be instantiating separate parsers. Or doing it directly on the parser instance.

Comment: @BrianJ.Miller that's even better

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 issues...

1. You have to resolve with a value if it passes...and reject with an error when it fails
2. You need to add a catch block to you promise handling chain to catch errors.

var xml2jsParser = require('xml2js').parseString;

```
function promisesParser(string)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        xml2jsParser(string, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
             } else {
                return resolve(result);
             }
        });
    });
}

var string = "<container><tag3>option3</tag3></container>";

promisesParser(string)
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be too late to this answer, but I thought to share what I have been using

One can use `parseStringPromise` method of `xml2js` with `await` keyword inside an `async` function.

```
import { parseStringPromise } from 'xml2js'

export const main = async () => {
    const leadsData = await parseStringPromise(docBody)
    console.log(leadsData)
}
```